# Temperature difference with continuous pumping

Tags: thermodynamics

So, one of my friends gave me this problem to work out and I am stuck at a critical juncture -- guess I need to brush up on my thermodynamics.

Basically, if I have a vessel and keep pumping it with a liquid at temp $T_1$, and the vessel has the same liquid and at time initial $t_0$ it has temp $T_0 > T_1$, they are mixed and then the same volume of liquid that went in comes out at some temperature change dT. What is this change? I know dT = dQ/(mass in vessel * specific heat). But what does $T(t)$ equal? (temperature as a function of time).

First I tried to use newtons law of cooling but since T initial is $dT$, I get a circular DE.

Anyway, it's not a homework problem, just I (as a physicist) am quite frustrated I don't know the solution! Think I am missing something simple.

Comment: I should add, they are perfectly mixed and use  approximations where necessary.

Answer (score 0):

In an infinitesimal interval $dt$ of pumping the heat ($Q$) balance is (by conservation of energy):

$$(dQ)_{in}-(dQ)_{out}=(dQ)_{tank}$$
Define $\dot{m}$ as the mass flow (in and out), $m$ the total mass of water in the tank, then with $dT$ the temperature change of the tank:
$$\dot{m}dtc_pT_1-\dot{m}dtc_p(T+dT)=mc_pdT$$
$$\dot{m}dtT_1-\dot{m}dtT-\dot{m}dtdT=mdT$$
Eliminate the second order infinitesimal and divide by $dt$:
$$\dot{m}dtT_1-\dot{m}dtT=mdT$$
$$\dot{m}T_1-\dot{m}T=m\frac{dT}{dt}$$
$$\frac{dT}{T_1-T}=\frac{\dot{m}}{m}dt$$
Integrate between $t=0, T=T_0$ and $t,T$:
$$\int_{T_0}^{T}\frac{dT}{T_1-T}=\frac{\dot{m}}{m}\int_0^tdt$$
$$-\ln\Big[\frac{T_1-T}{T_1-T_0}\Big]=\frac{\dot{m}}{m}t$$
Reworked we get:
$$\large{T(t)=T_1-(T_1-T_0)e^{-\frac{\dot{m}}{m}t}}$$
So, for $t \to \infty$, $T(t) \to T_1$.

---

**Edit:**

To demonstrate that in the solution to this problem $c_p$ plays no part we can take a different approach. Assume we start with a tank with $m$ mass at $T_0$. Now we add an aliquot $\Delta m$ at $T_1$ and mix. The heat balance then is:
$$mc_pT_0+\Delta m c_pT_1=(m+\Delta m)c_pT_2$$
The temperature of the tank is now $T_2$:
$$T_2=\frac{mT_0+\Delta m T_1}{m+\Delta m}$$
Then we take $\Delta m$ out of the tank and replace it with $\Delta m$ at $T_1$ and mix:
$$mc_pT_2+\Delta m c_pT_1=(m+\Delta m)c_pT_3$$
 $$T_3=\frac{mT_2+\Delta m T_1}{m+\Delta m}$$ 
Repeat: 
  $$mc_pT_3+\Delta m c_pT_1=(m+\Delta m)c_pT_4$$
 $$T_4=\frac{mT_3+\Delta m T_1}{m+\Delta m}$$
If we keep repeating this process an infinite number of times eventually the whole tank will be at $T_1$. But at no point does $c_p$ feature in the successive tank temperatures. It's the same if we assume constant additions and withdrawals, as above. In the limit for $\Delta m \to 0$ this solution becomes essentially the same as the one using differentials.

Comment: how does the T(t) answer not rely on c_p at all? If the liquid is water or honey it will be the same rate of heat transfer? that cant be right.

Comment: @renegade: as long as $c_p$ is a true constant, it drops out of the heat balance. This is not really a heat transfer problem. Work out e.g. what is the final temperature when you mix two *identical* liquids at different temperatures: there too the final temperature is independent of $c_p$. Only if the liquids have *different* values for $c_p$ do the $c_p$ values affect final temperature.

Comment: @renegade: for example, we mix $m_1$ at $T_1$ with $m_2$ at $T_2$, both the same liquid. The heat balance is: $m_1c_pT_1+m_2c_pT_2=(m_1+m_2)c_pT_f$. Then $T_f=(m_1T_1+m_2T_2)/(m_1+m_2)$. Honey, water, makes no difference: $T_f$ is invariant to $c_p$.

Comment: yes t_f is invariant, but the rate is not. so I am confused why T(t) would gave the same result for different liquids.

Comment: go back to the tank example that has an m_in and m_out. If I have the tank filled with water and measure the Temp at t=1 hour, and then change the setup to honey instead, and measure at t=1 hour -- you are saying the result will be the same? Intuitively this sounds wrong.

Comment: @renegade: I said that for *different* liquids the individual $c_p$ values would *have* to be taken into account. But you specified identical liquids, I quote: *"and the vessel has the same liquid"*. Not sure what rate you are referring to now?

Comment: @renegade:   *"Intuitively this sounds wrong."*. Intuition is a very bad guide in Science. Try and follow the reasoning from top to bottom, rather than as you did, start at the conclusion.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38799/discussion-between-gert-and-renegade).

Comment: Tomorrow I'll make an edit that will make things crystal clear. Good night.

Comment: @renegade This is a pretty nasty problem because the mass fractions of the components in the tank solution are going to be changing with time.  So a transient mass balance on the tank contents is going to be necessary to include to determine the transient mass fraction variation of the species.  Are you willing at least to make the approximation that the densities of the two fluids is about the same (even though their heat capacities may be different)?

Comment: @ChesterMiller: like all such mixing problems it (unrealistically) *assumes* that mixing is instant and 100 % thorough. Also, there's only one liquid with one density and one $c_p$.

Comment: @renegade: edit made. I hope this clarifies why $T(t)$ is invariant to $c_p$.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm very familiar with continuous stirred tank models.  I thought he was saying that the fluids had different heat capacities.

Comment: @ChesterMiller: no but renegade finds it hard to believe that with just one liquid, $c_p$ does not feature in the end solution for $T(t)$.

Comment: @Gert Well, if he can't do it for a single fluid, he certainly will never be able to do it for two fluids with different heat capacities.  Of course, in that case, the heat capacities do matter.

Comment: @ChesterMiller: I'm not sure where his disbelief comes from. For a single liquid this is almost a *banal* problem, if one accepts the instant, 100 % mixing problem, of course. A simple heat balance provides a separable DV. Case closed.